# Las rutas solo me redirigen a un componente en React

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Estoy intentando hacer las rutas públicas y privadas de mi proyecto, y quiero que cuando existe el token, se tenga acceso tanto a las rutas públicas como privadas, pero solamente me toma las rutas públicas, a continuación el código:

```
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";

import Footer from "../Footer/Footer";
import { NavBar } from "../NavBar/NavBar";
import PrivateRoutes from "../router/PrivateRoutes";
import PublicRoutes from "../router/PublicRoutes";

const Layout = () => {
// Componente para envolver a las rutas privadas
return (
    <>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <NavBar />
            <AnimatePresence>
                {localStorage.getItem("token") ? (
                    <>
                        <PrivateRoutes />
                        <PublicRoutes />
                    </>
                ) : (
                    <PublicRoutes />
                )}
            </AnimatePresence>
        </BrowserRouter>
        <Footer />
    </>
  );
 };

 export default Layout;
```

Este es el archivo en donde renderizan las rutas..
Y las rutas a continuación:

```
 const PrivateRoutes = () => {
 const pageTransition = {
initial: {
  opacity: 0,
  x: "-100vw",
},
animate: {
  x: 0,
  opacity: 1,
  transition: {
    duration: 1,
    ease: [0.6, -0.05, 0.01, 0.99],
  },
},
exit: {
  x: "-100vw",
  opacity: 0,
  transition: {
    duration: 1,
    ease: [0.6, -0.05, 0.01, 0.99],
  },
 },
};


return (
 <Routes>
  <Route
    path="/home"
    element={
      <motion.div
        className="page"
        initial="initial"
        animate="animate"
        exit="exit"
        variants={pageTransition}>
        <Home />
      </motion.div>
    }
  />

  <Route
    path="/charge"
    element={
      <motion.div
        className="page"
        initial="initial"
        animate="animate"
        exit="exit"
        variants={pageTransition}>
        <Charge />
      </motion.div>
    }
  />

  <Route
    path="/spents"
    element={
      <motion.div
        className="page"
        initial="initial"
        animate="animate"
        exit="exit"
        variants={pageTransition}>
        <Spents />
      </motion.div>
    }
  />

  <Route
    path="/balance"
    element={
      <motion.div
        className="page"
        initial="initial"
        animate="animate"
        exit="exit"
        variants={pageTransition}>
        <Balance />
      </motion.div>
    }
  />

  <Route
    path="/movements"
    element={
      <motion.div
        className="page"
        initial="initial"
        animate="animate"
        exit="exit"
        variants={pageTransition}>
        <Movements />
      </motion.div>
    }
  />

  <Route
    path="/transfers"
    element={
      <motion.div
        className="page"
        initial="initial"
        animate="animate"
        exit="exit"
        variants={pageTransition}>
        <Transfers />
      </motion.div>
    }
  />
</Routes>
 );
 };

export default PrivateRoutes;
```

Y las públicas:

```
  const PublicRoutes = () => {
  const pageTransition = {
 initial: {
   opacity: 0,
   x: "-100vw",
 },
 animate: {
  x: 0,
  opacity: 1,
  transition: {
    duration: 1,
    ease: [0.6, -0.05, 0.01, 0.99],
  },
 },
 exit: {
  x: "-100vw",
  opacity: 0,
  transition: {
    duration: 1,
    ease: [0.6, -0.05, 0.01, 0.99],
   },
  },
 };

  const Error404 = lazy(() => import("../views/Error404/Error404"));
  return (
<Routes>
  <Route
    path="/register"
    element={
      <motion.div
        className="page"
        initial="initial"
        animate="animate"
        exit="exit"
        variants={pageTransition}>
        <Register />
      </motion.div>
    }
  />

  <Route
    path="/"
    element={
      <motion.div
        className="page"
        initial="initial"
        animate="animate"
        exit="exit"
        variants={pageTransition}>
        <Login />
      </motion.div>
    }
  />

  <Route
    path="*"
    element={
      <motion.div
        className="page"
        initial="initial"
        animate="animate"
        exit="exit"
        variants={pageTransition}>
        <Suspense fallback={<>...</>}>
          <Error404 />
        </Suspense>
      </motion.div>
    }
  />
</Routes>
 );
};

export default PublicRoutes;
```

Con este código solo me redirige a las rutas públicas, pero quisiera que me permita el acceso a las 2, no sé si alguien me podría guiar o darme una mano con esto, muchas gracias!

Comment: Y esto funciona? "localStorage.getItem("token")" es decir, estás obteniendo el token? Porque en caso contrario siempre entraría al else(expresión 2) del ternario, haciendo que solo funcionen las públicas.
De todos modos hay algunas cosas para modificar, en general el <BrowserRouter> no se suele poner ahí, y las rutas privadas no se manejan de esa manera, además de que no tendría mucho sentido que las rutas públicas funcionen también estén dentro de la condición de "si hay un token".. Quizás el siguiente link te sea útil https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-router-private-routes/

Comment: SI, era un problema del token, gracias! ya encontré una forma mejor de manejar las rutas también! saludos.